# Swift : Width of CALayer after animation

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, caanimation

The code you see below creates a CALayer(rectangle shape) and animates it from the left to the right when the user holds down on the screen(longPressGestureRecognizer). When they lift their finger, the CALayer stops animating. You can copy and paste code directly in new project:

```
//Global Variables
var layer: CALayer?
var holdGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.width")

func setUpView() {

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(holdGesture)
    holdGesture.addTarget(self, action:"handleLongPress:")
}

func handleLongPress(sender : UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if(sender.state == .Began) {

        let newLayer = CALayer()
        newLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 10)
        newLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = self.view.bounds.width * 2
        animation.duration = 5
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)

        print("Long Press Began")
        newLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "bounds.size.width")

        layer = newLayer
    }
    else {
        print("Long press ended")

        if let layer = layer {
            pauseLayer(layer)
        }
    }
}

func pauseLayer(layer : CALayer){
    let pausedTime : CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil)
    layer.speed = 0.0

    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime
}
```

When the "Long press ended" has occurred(user lifts finger) there is a new width to the layer. However, when i print it, it says its "0.0". I do not know why. How can I get the width of the layer after the animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:** you can get the values as they appear during an animation through the `presentationLayer()` of the layer.

---

You've encountered the difference between the layer's model value and its presentation value. When you add an animation to a layer, it only changes how the layer appears on screen (the presentation value) but not the actual property being animated (the model value).

When simply animating from one value to another, one would normally set the animated property to it's final value so that the model and the presentation will be the same after the animation completes.

However, since it looks like you are pausing the animation before it completes, that won't give you the value as it currently appears on screen (the presentation value). Instead, you can ask a layer for it's presentation layer which holds (a close approximation of) the current values as they appear on screen.

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you so much. This helps greatly.